# Best practice to work with the same web service from different subdomains

Tags: ajax, web-services, architecture, cross-domain

I have web application with multiple client UI's (Desktop browser application, mobile, tablet, reporting etc.). All of them are html-css-javascript applications, that retrieve data via REST web services.
Most of the web services are used across applications, and only few of them are dedicated to one application.

I want to make the applications separated by subdomains:

```
webservices.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
mobile.mydoaim.com
reporting.mydomain.com
```

What is the best practice for doing that and maintain ajax calls, despite the different url "locations"?

Comment: CORS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: JSONP looks like an option. How are the mobile browsers with it?

Comment: JSONP is basically just embedding a script resource via a `script` element – so really nothing different from embedding a script from say Google Analytics. This script gets executed like any other script you embed into your page, with no differentiation between scripts loaded from your own domain or a different one. Since embedding script resources into pages is “the oldest thing in the book”, I think there should be no problems at all in mobile browsers.

Comment: I thought that browsers treat JSONP in a different way (due to adding the <script> time dynamically or executing 3d party code in a way that reminds "eval"). But it is working well. I have only one problem with it- one of the WS includes upload of file (which requires POST)

Comment: Please note that the webservices' authentication is cookie based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX calls can be to the server hosting the page and internally that server can make a b2b call to the actual REST service (mobile.mydomain.com, reporting.mydomain.com etc). You don't have to call the cross domain URL from the UI. Just proxy it through the server hosting the page.

Comment: b2b as in server to server. Instead of doing client->Backend, I am suggesting doing Client-> Web application (which serves up your UI pages)->Backend. Calling a service is very trivial, so I don't think there will be any major code duplication.

Comment: A caveat about JSONP, if your services are used by other applications which are not calling it from a browser, you need to add in logic in your services to respond appropriately. i.e. JSONP if coming from mobile vs xml/json if coming from somewhere else.

Comment: My WS are returning JSON, and consumed by libraries such as dojo and jquery, so adjusting them to JSONP is as easy as wrapping the response with a 'callback' function. However, I have one WS that must wirk with POST because it allows file uploading.

Comment: So what do you think about consuming all the other WS (located in webservices.mydomain.com) using JSONP and build a proxy page in the other domain for that particular POST WS?

Comment: Another question: is building such proxy is better than taking any logic possible from the WS itself to an external class and then make a "thin" web service that only sends parameters to the same class?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, but I think what you are looking for is content negotiation in your APIs. If you can cleanly respond to all content types in your APIs without cluttering your code base, go for all logic in the WS and use JSONP for cross domain calls. If existing your WS are tough due to whatever reasons (legacy code etc), you might need a content negotiation layer.